# Count occurrences in a specific column in a .csv, without extra characters

Tags: python, csv

> ```
> StartDate EndDate Days    Strategy
> 1/4/11    1/20/11 11   Multi #1
> 1/21/11   1/27/11 4    Multi #18
> 1/28/11   1/31/11 1    Multi #8
> 1/31/11   2/3/11  3    Multi #20
> 2/7/11    2/9/11  2    Multi #10
> 2/9/11    2/23/11 9    Multi #5
> 2/23/11   3/4/11  7    Multi #16
> 3/11/11   3/14/11 1    Multi #20
> 3/15/11   3/22/11 5    Multi #20
> ```

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('/input.csv') as f:
    next(f)  # skip header
    occurrence = Counter(tuple(row[3:4]) for row in csv.reader(f))
print(occurrence)

with open('/output.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Strategy', 'Counts'])
    for (src), cnt in occurrence.items():
        writer.writerow([src, cnt])
```

On top is a sample of a larger comma separated CSV and my code so far in Python 3. I'd like to read the file and count the number of times each Strategy occurs. The code above outputs what I want, but with extra characters. I'd like the rows to look like:

```
>Multi #1,1 
>Multi #18,1
>Multi #8,1
>Multi #20,3
```

Instead, rows look like:

```
> "(' Multi #18',)",3
```

Do I need to use another way of counting the column to get the desired result? Is there a better way to select the Strategy column for counting?

Comment: Can you add an example of your desired output ?

Comment: Added larger sample of desired output.

Comment: Why do you need it as tuple and why `row[3:4]`? Just use `occurrence = Counter([row[3] for row in csv.reader(f)])` and then you can use `occurrence.most_common()` to get the total occurrences for each string.

Comment: Simple fix. Thanks Dekel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're slicing unnecessarily. Note the difference between `row[3:4]` (which gives a list with one string) and `row[3]` (which is just the string):

```
>>> row = ['1/4/11', '1/20/11', '11', 'Multi #1']
>>> row[3:4]
['Multi #1']
>>> tuple(row[3:4])
('Multi #1',)
>>> row[3]
'Multi #1'
```

You want to replace this:

```
Counter(tuple(row[3:4]) for row in csv.reader(f))
```

With this:

```
Counter(row[3] for row in csv.reader(f))
```

Another (less preferable) way to fix your problem would be to add a comma in the parenthesis in your `for` loop unpacking, so that `src` becomes the item in the single-item tuple, and not the whole tuple:

```
for (src,), cnt in occurrence.items():
    writer.writerow([src, cnt])
```

I'm guessing you were slicing for multiple columns previously.

If you just use indexing (`row[3]`) instead of slicing (`row[3:4]`), you can remove the parenthesis on the `for` loop instead:

```
for src, cnt in occurrence.items():
    writer.writerow([src, cnt])
```

Comment: You are correct. I was adapting code from another thread that used two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the last two entries in each row, splitting them off by white space:

```
with open('/input.csv') as fobj:
    next(fobj)
    occurrence = Counter(' '.join(line.rsplit(None, 2)[-2:]) for line in fobj)
```

Keeping the rest of your code gives this output file:

```
Strategy,Counts
Multi #1,1
Multi #18,1
Multi #20,3
Multi #5,1
Multi #10,1
Multi #8,1
Multi #16,1
```

`csv.reader` does not really work for reading this input data. It can only split entries in a row by by one character such as comma, a semicolon, or a space. Since the separators between columns are spaces and the content of the last column contains a space, it seems simpler to use the `split()`, or in this case the `rsplit()`, method of a string to get to content of the last column.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your input file is called `input_file`.

You can solve your problem using `itertools.groupby` like the example below:

```
data = tuple(k.strip("\n").split("#") for k in open("input_file", 'r'))


from itertools import groupby
a, b = dict(), list()
for k, v in groupby(data[1:], lambda x : x[1]):
    b = list(v)
    if k in a.keys():
        c = a[k]
        a[k] = c + len(b)
    else:
        a[k] = len(b)


for i in a.keys():
    print("Multi #{0},{1}".format(i, a[i]))
```

Output:

```
Multi #1,1
Multi #5,1
Multi #10,1
Multi #16,1
Multi #20,3
Multi #18,1
Multi #8,1
```